# How to clear cache of all running applications android?

Tags: android, caching

In My application i tried to delete other applications cache memory using the following code. But it is deleting my application cache only Not the others applications.

code like this:

```
public void clearApplicationData() 
     {
File cache = getCacheDir();
File appDir = new File(cache.getParent());
if (appDir.exists()) {
    String[] children = appDir.list();
    for (String s : children) {
        if (!s.equals("lib")) {
            deleteDir(new File(appDir, s));
            Log.i("TAG", "**************** File /data/data/APP_PACKAGE/" + s + " DELETED *******************");
        }
    }
}
}

  public static boolean deleteDir(File dir) 
    {
if (dir != null && dir.isDirectory()) {
    String[] children = dir.list();
    for (int i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
        boolean success = deleteDir(new File(dir, children[i]));
        if (!success) {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
return dir.delete();
}
```

Comment: would you really like some app that cleared YOUR app cache?

Comment: @Sairam have u found anything regarding this if yes can u pls share ?